# Encoding issues with T4 generation

Tags: c#, encoding, t4

I am trying to generate some version file with T4 with some specific characters in it. Here I am looking to generate some text containing a copyright symbol : ©

Problem : There is clearly an encoding issue because the output files doesn't display it (interrogation point)

I made sure that both my .tt and my output file are with the same encoding : ANSI.

I tried various thing such as using the encoding="windows-1252" or other encodings (like utf-16) in the output section of T4 with the .tt file being of that encoding but so far I found no way of having the expected result.

I am generating my file as simply as the following :

```
TextTransform.exe [-out myFile.h] myFile.tt
```

The easiest I could make so I reproduce it is :

*myFile.tt*

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
©
```

Expected : ©

Actual : Bad character (usually ?)

Comment: I tried it on myself, but I'm using in my projects UTF-8 for all my files. Also when I added a new text template to my project it was a UTF-8-BOM file per default and there everything works as expected.

Comment: Well, UTF-8 works, I tried to generate in UTF-8 but I think the .tt was still in ANSI. 

Now I just need to check if UTF-8 as output is ok for my needs (building code purposes)

Comment: For me the easiest way to check and change the encoding of a file is open it in Notepad++. Here you see the current encoding of the file in the lower right corner and can easily be converted to a different encoding by using the "Encoding" menu in the menu bar.

Comment: Thank you, I already knew it. I just wasn't sure if UTF8 would suit my needs but it seems like it's working well with UTF8 so I'll keep on with that encoding. Thank you, your first comment actually gave me the idea of changing the original file encoding which resolved the issue. This is resolved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by changing the encoding of the .tt file to UTF8

The problem with ANSI is yet unknown but in my case, ANSI was not necessary.